# Does tkinter tag_add create a single tag when ranges overlap?

Tags: python, tkinter, tags

I'm writing a simple application that has a search function using tkinter. I've successfully implemented the search function, but have found that when it finds two search fields that are next to each other (e.g., no space between them), and I add a highlight tag for both fields, tkinter appears to combine the two tag_add entries into one range. Here's some example code that demonstrates this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
T = tk.Text(root, height=10, width=50)
T.pack()
string = """This is some example text
This is some more example text
In this line exampleexample occurs twice
This is the last example line"""
T.insert(tk.END, string)
find_length = IntVar()
pos = T.search("example", "1.0", stopindex=END, count=find_length, nocase=1)
while pos:
    print ("pos = ", pos)
    print("length =", find_length.get())
    end = "%s+%sc" % (pos, find_length.get())
    print ("end =", end, "\n")
    T.tag_add('highlight', pos, end)
    T.tag_configure('highlight', foreground ='red')
    pos = T.search("example", end, stopindex=END, count=find_length, nocase=1)

print (T.tag_ranges('highlight'))

tk.mainloop()
```

The output of this example code looks like this:

```
pos =  1.13
length = 7
end = 1.13+7c 

pos =  2.18
length = 7
end = 2.18+7c 

pos =  3.13
length = 7
end = 3.13+7c 

pos =  3.20
length = 7
end = 3.20+7c 

pos =  4.17
length = 7
end = 4.17+7c 

(<textindex object: '1.13'>, <textindex object: '1.20'>, <textindex object: '2.18'>, <textindex object: '2.25'>, <textindex object: '3.13'>, <textindex object: '3.27'>, <textindex object: '4.17'>, <textindex object: '4.24'>)
```

And here's a link to the results: [Tkinter Tag example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xyNa6CQ-lC0NsfEoJSNKhwoJNkUpgbEm/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, I've done a tag_add for each search result. But the result for the "exampleexample" in the third line have been combined into one range 3.13 - 3.27.

I'm assuming that this is working as designed. But thought I would ask the community if there might be something I am overlooking or doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm assuming that this is working as designed.

You are correct, your example is working as designed.

Tags aren't objects, they are attributes assigned to a range of characters<sup>1</sup>. Once you've added a tag, tkinter essentially forgets how the tag was added. Whether you call `tag_add` ten times for 10 consecutive characters or call it once for the range of 10 characters, the end result is the same -- tkinter simply knows that those 10 characters have the same tag.

This is how many programs work. For example, when I search for "example" on this web page in chrome, `exampleexample` is highlighted as if it were one match.

[image: screenshot]

---

<sup>1</sup> That's not entirely correct. A tag is also an object managed by the text widget. However, no matter how many ranges of text have a particular tag, there is only one instance of each tag. This single tag object is used to hold the configuration values for that tag.

Comment: thanks Bryan. I figured that was the case. Just wanted to verify. My task will be to treat the two back-to-back "examples" as two instances. I'll just build a list of search matches and handle them that way.